# Error: undefined reference to `sqlite3_open'

Tags: c++, sqlite

I'm trying to get started with the C++ API for SQLite.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sqlite3.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    sqlite3 *db;
    if (sqlite3_open("ex1.db", &db) == SQLITE_OK)
        cout << "Opened db successfully\n";
    else
        cout << "Failed to open db\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Compiling this using the command "g++ main.cpp" gives the following error:

```
/tmp/ccu8sv4b.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x64): undefined reference to `sqlite3_open'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What could have gone wrong? Hasn't sqlite3 properly installed in the server I'm compiling this in?

Comment: What compiler platform are you using ? Make sure you build sqlite.c and include it with your program. +Don't forget to close your connection...

Comment: undefined reference to `sqlite3_open'

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You need to link the sqlite3 library along with your program:

```
g++ main.cpp -lsqlite3
```

Comment: In an Android environment, this caused me to see: fatal error: 'jni.h' file not found

Comment: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsqlite3

Comment: @CSQGB have u installed libsqlite3-dev?

Answer (score 7):

You need to adjust your linker flags to link in the `sqlite3` library. Libraries are usually installed in `/usr/lib` or `/usr/lib64`

Alternatively, you can copy the `sqlite3.c` file to your project directory and compile it as part of the `g++` command:

```
g++ main.cpp sqlite3.c
```

as per: http://sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=HowToCompile

Comment: Site says that page contains obsolete information, directs user to this page: http://sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=HowToCompile

Comment: This seems to be the current page https://www.sqlite.org/howtocompile.html

Answer (score 1):

**First step:** Install all library sqlite3 with the command:

```
        sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
```

With that you can use `#include <sqlite3.h>` in  a programm of `C` or `C++`.

**Second step:** To compile the program by console:

**C++:**

```
        g++ program.cpp -o executable -lsqlite3

        ./executable
```

**C:**

```
        gcc program.c -o executable -lsqlite3

        ./executable
```

Comment: `/usr/bin/c++  -lsqlite3   qgb.cpp`  undefined reference to `sqlite3_close'

Comment: already `apt install libsqlite3-dev`

Answer (score 0):

Either link your program to lib g++ yourProgram.c -lsqlite3 in command line or in Open IDE -> project -> properties -> locate lib file for sqlite3 .

Answer (score 0):

### Compile using `Devcpp`

**1.** add `sqlite3.dll` file in the project folder.

**2.** go to Compiler option in Tools >>

**3.** write `sqlite3.dll` next to *>>* **Add the following commands when calling compiler**

[image: Screen shot]

### Compile using command line

**NOTE** : *install MinGW (compiler)*

`g++ file.cpp -o output.exe sqlite3.dll`

### Compile using **VS**

*define `sqlite3.dll` in linker in project properties*