# Reference error I got from sqlite3 library when using C

Tags: c, sqlite

I need to do an assignment using SQLite3 in C. I am familiar with basic SQLite usage in Java and C#, but I am not familiar with C, and the error I have been encountering for the past five days is driving me crazy.How do I need to install the SQLite3 library on my computer, or even though I have added the header file, I'm still getting a reference error? I'm having trouble with these issues.

When I add the SQLite3 header and .c file to a C project I created in Visual Studio Code or DevC++, I encounter the error "undefined reference to: 'sqlite3_open'" during compilation. I have limited knowledge about C and couldn't find much information online, so I'm confused. I would greatly appreciate it if you could explain to me step by step what I need to do. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: undefined reference to \`sqlite3\_open'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9389344/error-undefined-reference-to-sqlite3-open)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: no, I couldn't find the sqlite3.lib file on the internet, I have the header and .c file